# How to reduce code complexity while using multiple if else in Apex?

Tags: apex

I have the following code where I initially thought of using ternary operator but as ternary operator returns a value and this method is of type void Im clueless on how to reduce the number of if else statements. Code Quality fails due to cyclomatic complexity (too many if else)

```
 public static void setFavouriteOrUnfavouriteAccount(SelectedAccount selectedAcc, SelectedAccount selAccountShipTo, List<Account> favouriteAccounts){

    if(selAccountShipTo == null){

    
        if(selectedAcc.isFav){
            favouriteAccounts[0].MCX_isUserFavourite__c = false;
        }
        else{
            favouriteAccounts[0].MCX_isUserFavourite__c = true;
        }

    }
    else{
       
        if(selAccountShipTo.isFav){
            favouriteAccounts[0].MCX_isUserFavourite__c = false;
        }
        else{
            favouriteAccounts[0].MCX_isUserFavourite__c = true;
        }

    }
    
 }
```

This method is called in another method. Is there a way to reduce the code complexity here?

Comment: Please stick to tags that describe what the question is about (there is no SOQL or SalesforceDX component to this question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I look at this code, what I see is *duplication*. As a rule of thumb, duplication is bad. DRY (don't repeat yourself) code is usually better than WET (write everything twice/thrice) code. This is a rule of thumb and not gospel, but in this case there are definitely clear improvements that can be made.

First, let's look at the inner if/else

```java
if(selectedAcc.isFav){
    favouriteAccounts[0].MCX_isUserFavourite__c = false;
}
else{
    favouriteAccounts[0].MCX_isUserFavourite__c = true;
}
```

If we ignore the account you're working on

- you're setting the same field in both branches
- the value you're using is tied to `isFav`
- you're covering all possible cases for `isFav` (well, except for null)

That's telling me that the if/else is completely unnecessary here. This code could be replaced with

```java
favouriteAccounts[0].MCX_isUserFavourite__c = !selectedAcc.isFav;
```

Next, let's look at the outer if/else

```java
if(selAccountShipTo == null){
    // use selectedAcc
}
else{
    // use selAccountShipTo
}
```

The code inside both is the same, you're just choosing which account to use.
The way you've structured it means it takes a bit more cognitive load to understand (if you mention thing A in the condition, it's easier to understand if you continue to use thing A in the body). Here, you're using thing A in the condition and thing B in the body. That's not super important, but it is worth mentioning.

Our quest here is to reduce duplication. So instead of repeating your code in the if/else blocks, why not select which account you'll be using first, *then* do the rest of the work?

```java
SelectedAccount workingAccount = selAccountShipTo != null ? selAccountShipTo : selectedAccount;

favouriteAccounts[0].MCX_isUserFavourite__c = !workingAccount.isFav;
```

There are probably other improvements that need to be made here (can the caller take responsibility for providing a single, non-null `SelectedAccount`? what if both are null? what if `isFav` is null? what if favouriteAccounts is null or empty?) but the main point here is that through the lens of "reduce duplication" it was possible to remove if/else.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a single statement

```js
 public static void setFavouriteOrUnfavouriteAccount(SelectedAccount selectedAcc, SelectedAccount selAccountShipTo, List<Account> favouriteAccounts){
    
    favouriteAccounts[0].MCX_isUserFavourite__c = (selAccountShipTo == null && !selectedAcc.isFav) || (selAccountShipTo != null && !selAccountShipTo.isFav);
    
 }
```

Comment: Code readability matters more than clever short code, keep it simple.