# How to reduce code complexity in LWC JS while iterating over different data sets?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, javascript

I have the following code snippet in LWC JS File for mobile functionality:

```
 handleRowSelectionMob(event){
        if(this.isMyDistrictActive){
            this.districtData?.forEach(d => {
                d.isChecked = d.districtName === event.target.value ? true : false;
            });
            this.selectedObject = this.districtData?.find( d => d.districtName === event.target.value);
        } else if(this.isAccountActive){
            this.accountsData?.forEach(d => {
                d.isChecked = d.accountName === event.target.value ? true : false;
            });
            this.selectedObject = this.accountsData?.find( d => d.accountName === event.target.value);
        } else if(this.isMyTeamActive){
            this.myTeamsData?.forEach(d =>{
                d.isChecked = d.accountName === event.target.value?true:false;
            });
            this.selectedObject = this.myTeamsData?.find( d => d.accountName === event.target.value);
        }       
        else if(this.isFavoritesActive){
            this.favAccData?.forEach(d => {
                d.isChecked = d.accountName === event.target.value ? true : false;
            });
            this.selectedObject = this.favAccData?.find( d => d.accountName === event.target.value);
        }
        this.disableSelectBtn = false;
        this.selectedRows = [this.selectedObject.id];
    }
```

Issue is that CodeScan quality gate is reporting this as having Cognitive Complexity of 16 and asks me to reduce it to 15 as the image below:
[image]

The total count of the red numbers is 16. It says 15 is allowed.
Im unable to reduce the code complexity of this method

Comment: This feels quite similar to a previous question of yours that I answered: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/404711/how-to-reduce-code-complexity-while-using-multiple-if-else-in-apex
What lessons from that do you think you might be able to apply here as well?

Comment: There in both the cases the logic was applied on the same data. But here if u see with each if and else there is different dataset thats why Im struggling. If you see clearly within the if statements every block deals with a different dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that you didn't DRY your code ("Don't Repeat Yourself"). By adding a helper function, you can eliminate all but one of the if statements.

```
  handleRowSelectionMob(event) {
    // Field names
    const [districtName, accountName] = ["districtName", "accountName"];
    // Evaluation function
    const eq = (value) => value === event.target.value;
    const fn = (active, items, field) => {
      if (!active || !items) {
        return false;
      }
      items.forEach((d) => { d.isChecked = eq(d[field]) });
      this.selectedObject = items.find((d) => eq(d[field]));
      return true;
    };
    // For each configuration
    [
      [this.isMyDistrictActive, this.districtData, districtName],
      [this.isAccountActive, this.accountsData, accountName],
      [this.isMyTeamActive, this.myTeamsData, accountName],
      [this.isFavoritesActive, this.favAccData, accountName],
    ].find((config) => fn(...config));
  }
```

Of course, you might find more legible ways of writing this, but this is fairly standard JS optimization.

Comment: sorry as Im a javascript noob but the configuration defined in the end is named as items? ur iterating over the items array just asking how it is setup. And 2 more Questions - where is field defined in  the d[field]. And the const [districtName, accountName] = ["districtName", "accountName"];   is this an array declaration?

Comment: @Amax1 See [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [Arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for the language features I've used here.

Comment: @Amax1 `const [districtName, accountName] = ["districtName", "accountName"];` is destructuring assignment, `(active, items, field) => { ... }` is the arrow function, and `fn(...config)` is the spread syntax.

Comment: but I used ur code and it throws another issue. Im attaching the link. Need your help here : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/405988/getting-return-value-of-find-must-be-used-while-optimizing-js-in-lwc