# Getting return value of find must be used while Optimizing JS in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, javascript, performance

Im running the following code to optimize iteration in different datasets. BAsically Im avoiding multiple if statements here. But it says the return value of find must be used. Here is the code

```
  handleRowSelectionMob(event){

               // Field names
    const [districtName, accountName] = ["districtName", "accountName"];
    // Evaluation function
    const eq = (value) => value === event.target.value;
    const fn = (active, items, field) => {
      if (!active || !items) {
        return false;
      }
      items.forEach((d) => { d.isChecked = eq(d[field]) });
      this.selectedObject = items.find((d) => eq(d[field]));
      return true;
    };
    // For each configuration
    [
      [this.isMyDistrictActive, this.districtData, districtName],
      [this.isAccountActive, this.accountsData, accountName],
      [this.isMyTeamActive, this.myTeamsData, accountName],
      [this.isFavoritesActive, this.favAccData, accountName],
    ].find((config) => fn(...config));
    
        this.disableSelectBtn = false;
        this.selectedRows = [this.selectedObject.id];
    }
```

It shows below error
[image]

Where do I assign this? This code was the alternative to the below code

```
 handleRowSelectionMob(event){

         
        if(this.isMyDistrictActive){
            this.districtData?.forEach(d => {
                d.isChecked = d.districtName === event.target.value ? true : false;
            });
            this.selectedObject = this.districtData?.find( d => d.districtName === event.target.value);
        } else if(this.isAccountActive){
            this.accountsData?.forEach(d => {
                d.isChecked = d.accountName === event.target.value ? true : false;
            });
            this.selectedObject = this.accountsData?.find( d => d.accountName === event.target.value);
        } else if(this.isMyTeamActive){
            this.myTeamsData?.forEach(d =>{
                d.isChecked = d.accountName === event.target.value?true:false;
            })
            this.selectedObject = this.myTeamsData?.find( d => d.accountName === event.target.value);
        }       
        else if(this.isFavoritesActive){
            this.favAccData?.forEach(d => {
                d.isChecked = d.accountName === event.target.value ? true : false;
            });
            this.selectedObject = this.favAccData?.find( d => d.accountName === event.target.value);
        }
        this.disableSelectBtn = false;
        this.selectedRows = [this.selectedObject.id];
    }
```

Comment: @sfdcfox your suggestion would help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really an error, just a best practice sort of thing. You can just provide a dummy variable in its place:

```
 const uselessVar = [
      [this.isMyDistrictActive, this.districtData, districtName],
      [this.isAccountActive, this.accountsData, accountName],
      [this.isMyTeamActive, this.myTeamsData, accountName],
      [this.isFavoritesActive, this.favAccData, accountName],
    ].find((config) => fn(...config));
```